# Bold Text Lost in Translation

Tags: android

The Toast is showing the string wodString underlined and bolded like I have it in the string.xml.  On the next line when I try to set the text of wod_type it presents the text without bolding or underlining.  I've tried casting, Html.fromHtml(), etc.  Anybody know what else I can try?
PS: wod_type is a TextView

```
CharSequence[] s = getResources().getTextArray(R.array.wod_style_array);
    CharSequence wodString = s[position];
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), wodString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    wod_type.setText(wodString + m.wodScoring[position]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wodString + m.wodScoring[position]` is the problem. The `+` operator concatenates `CharSequence`s to a single `String`. However, a `String` cannot hold the styling information.

You can use [`TextUtils.concat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#concat%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29) to avoid these problems:

```
text.setText(TextUtils.concat(wodString, m.wodScoring[position]));
```

If `m.wodScoring[position]` is not a `String`, use an appropriate method to create one (e.g. `Integer.toString`).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Perfect explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use spannable string class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

```
String tempString="Copyright";
TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
text.setText(spanString);
```